# Implement Unit of Work with multiple databases

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to implement Unit of Work and Generic Repository by following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) great article. Only difference is that I have multiple databases context in my app. I came up with the below implementation but it seems awkward to say the least. What's the best way to do it ?

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private MainDBDataContext MainDBDataContext = new MainDBDataContext();
    private ReferenceDBDataContext ReferenceDBDataContext = new ReferenceDBDataContext();
    private ProjectDBDataContext projectDBDataContext = new ProjectDBDataContext();

    private VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public VehicleRepository VehicleRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.vehicleRepository == null)
            {
                this.vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(projectDBDataContext,ReferenceDBDataContext);
            }
            return vehicleRepository;
        }
    }

    public AccountRepository AccountRepository
    {
        get {
            if (this.accountRepository == null)
            {
                this.accountRepository = new AccountRepository(projectDBDataContext);
            }
            return accountRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        projectDBDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        ReferenceDBDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        MainDBDataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }


    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                projectDBDataContext.Dispose();
                MainDBDataContext.Dispose();
                ReferenceDBDataContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Dependency Injection. look at [this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: Multiple databases of the same schema or multiple databases of different schemas?

Comment: Same schema, still now answer.